# Form validation with jQuery and Codeigniter?

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter

Is there any tutorial or other helpful resource to create form validation with **jQuery** using **Codeigniter 2.0.2**
I have been searching but didnt find any. As I've just started learning Codeigniter, I'd prefer to have some helpful tutorial or any resource instead of already built-in liberary.
Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- jQuery
  http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation
- CodeIgniter
  http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/form_validation.html